# Optional Calendar type field in JSF form

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, calendar

I want to make a Calendar input in a JSF form optional. When the user doesn't inform the birth, the Calendar field must stay null.

**My code:**

```
@Model
public class Registration {
private User user = new User();

    public void register() {
        // stuff
    }
//getUser
}
```

**The model class:**

```
public class User { 
    //other fields
    private Calendar birth;
    // gets and sets
}
```

**The page:**

```
<h:outputLabel for="birth" value="Birth Date" />
<h:inputText id="birth" value="#{registration.user.birth.time}" >
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
</h:inputText>
```

The problem here so far is the `<f:convertDateTime>`, that depends of the `getTime()` method of `Calendar` to make the conversion. It throws a NPE (Null Pointer Exception) when executed. I know that if I initialize the birth the problem is solved, but I really want the field to be null when the user does not fill the field.

Any thoughts of a way to achive this?

Comment: It is the default behaviour of the f:convertDateTime Converter. if the string is null or empty string it will return null which is a cause for NPE. You can write a custom converter which is will give a date value such as 31-Jan-2999 which means that user entered null or empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, I'll post this for posterity. I think this would do the job:

```
@FacesConverter("CustomCalendarConverter")
public class CalConverter implements Converter{

@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
    if(value != null && !value.toString().isEmpty()){
        try {
            String pattern = (String) component.getAttributes().get("pattern");
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTime(new SimpleDateFormat(pattern).parse(value));
            return calendar;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {

    if(value != null && !value.toString().isEmpty()){
        Calendar cal = (Calendar) value;
        String pattern = (String) component.getAttributes().get("pattern");
        return new SimpleDateFormat(pattern).format(cal.getTime());
    }
        else return null;
    }
}
```

And the view should be:

```
<h:outputLabel for="birth" value="Birth Date" />
<h:inputText id="birth" value="#{registration.user.birth}">
    <f:converter converterId="CustomCalendarConverter" />
    <f:attribute name="pattern" value="dd/MM/yyyy" />
</h:inputText>
```

You can create a composite component too, something like `<custom:inputCalendar>` for instance.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not related to the convert, but to the expression:

`#{registration.user.birth.time}`

Infact this is `DateTimeConverter` code:

```
 public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
                          String value) {

    ...

    Object returnValue = null;
    DateFormat parser = null;

    try {

        // If the specified value is null or zero-length, return null
        if (value == null) {
            return (null);
        }
        value = value.trim();
        if (value.length() < 1) {
            return (null);
        }

        ...
         returnValue = parser.parse(value);

     } catch (ParseException e) {
       ...
     }
     return returnValue;
  }
```

As you can notice, null and empty values are managed rightly.
But when the values are applied, the expression `birth.time` is evaluated, but the `birth` reference is null, so when the setter on time is called you get NPE.

A possibile solution is to bind the `birth` field to `java.util.Date` type directly, which is the type managed by the `DateTimeConverter`, as below:

```
public class User { 
    //other fields
    private Date birth;
    // gets and sets
}
```